# Variable arguments without first argument - what belongs in va_start?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want to make `varargs` function for freeing multiple pointers at once, mostly to clean up the code. So I have:

```
void free_all( ... ) {
    va_list arguments;
    /* Initializing arguments to store all values after last arg */
    // but there are no args!
    va_start ( arguments, ????? );
    /* we expect the caller to send last argument as NULL **/
    void* pointer = va_arg ( arguments, void* );
    while( (pointer = va_arg ( arguments, void* ))!=NULL ) {
        free(pointer);
    }
    va_end ( arguments );                  // Cleans up the list
}
```

So what to put in `va_start ( arguments, ????? )`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply not possible. You MUST have a non vararg argument, always. In your case

```
void free_all(void *first, ...);
```

could work.

Comment: Is that a technical limitation, or simply something not implemented? (Here I'm simply curious how it works)

Comment: It is the way it works. It would be impossible to implement it otherwise. At least I think it would be.

Comment: @TomášZato, it's an oversight by the standard IMO. That extra argument is a hook into the stack frame. Theoretically, it could be accomplished without it.

Comment: @StoryTeller I was going to say it couldn't, but then I thought exactly of that. There must be a historical reason though.

Comment: @iharob, they probably reasoned that the feature can't be useful without sending some information about the extra parameters. And that translated to requiring at least one fixed parameter.

Comment: You could try the legacy `<varargs.h>` interface which supports variadic functions without fixed arguments. I wouldn't advise actually trying to use it but it clearly isn't a completely impossible feature, though it may well be difficult to support on certain systems. Presumably the rationale for modifying the interfaces in C89 should detail to official reasons for the choice.

Comment: @TomášZato: It's simply because the C standard says so. You could make your own extension of C that supports this somehow, but it wouldn't be standard C.